# How can I get the web path of chrome application model element in to a data item in blue prism?

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I am trying to get the web path for an element in to a data item. I need to manipulate it to access the next element. I am using Web Browser (Chrome) model. I have not been able to find an option for this in the Read stage. Is there a way to do this? Or is it possible to get the application modeler element in code stage to access its properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems getting the web path is not possible. Especially since blue prism does not appear to get the web path at run time. Rather it gets the web path when we spy the element.